# Crystal Report Folder Location

Tags: asp.net

Not sure if I am in the right position to ask this question but I've done my research and didn't find any answer. I am creating a web application and have organised my files (aspx, js, images, ashx and etc). I have crystal reports and I am not sure if I am planning to put them all in a separate folder called 'Reports' but I am not sure whether it is correct because when the application becomes bigger and bigger it might be cramped that all reports is in one folder? What do you guys think? Is there any guide to organising files and folders for web app?

Thanks in advance for answering this question!

Regards,

Harland

Answer (score 0):

We do keep them in "Reports" folder and then organize different reports by their categories (Merges, Payments, etc).

It is really more a convention, than a requirement.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, Do I have to create folders for every category under reports folder (payroll, sales etc)?

Comment: Whatever makes sense to you or any other developer in the future. We keep (relative) report path's in a database Reports table so nesting report folders inside Reports folder is easy